# Docker engine has failed to start error on ARM64 Linux

Tags: systemd, docker, arm64

I have recently received a rock pi 5B and migrated over my docker containers from my old raspberry pi.

The issue that I am having is that it will not work on either the raspberry pi nor the rock pi 5B now, displaying docker engine has failed to start.

I have tried reinstalling docker, removing the socket for docker, changing the config files in /etc/systemd for it but that has failed to get it to work. I have attempted to set the port 2736, that has also failed. I have tried removing the .JSON file and reinstalling docker.io but that has not worked. I have also tried the script from docket, which is still bringing up the same results.

Comment: What were you running them on before? Was it also ARM64?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run images built from a different architecture you can install [quemu-static](https://packages.debian.org/sid/qemu-user-static).

Under normal circumstances it's better to re-build the image or otherwise get an image for the correct architecture.  Using emulation like quemu will have a performance overhead.